# I can not find the error in the code.a picture Box does not update

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm creating a software in which `pictureBox2` updates with the color of the pixel clicked on `pictureBox1`.

Already tried to use `refresh()`, but `pictureBox2` does not change.

```cs
private void PictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    color = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y); // Color

    solidColor = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb); //Image
    using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(solidColor))
    {
        SolidBrush co = new SolidBrush(color);
        grp.FillRectangle( co, 0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
    }

    pictureBox2.Image = solidColor;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you're getting the right color from `pictureBox1`? Have you tried changing `color ` to something manually to see if `pictureBox2` updates?

Comment: I've tested your code and worked fine in here. Do you have any error on your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing this.

````cs
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
            Point cord= me.Location;
            color = b.GetPixel(cord.X,cord.Y); 

            solidColor = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(solidColor))
            {

                SolidBrush co = new SolidBrush(color);
                grp.FillRectangle(co, 0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);

            }

            pictureBox2.Image = solidColor;

        }
```c#
````

Comment: You should dispose the image that's already in pictureBox2 before putting in a new one, otherwise you will get out-of-memory errors if this is executed regularly. Though, in general, this whole thing can be replaced by just setting the background colour of `pictureBox2` to that colour. There is no need to create a bitmap at all.